# Angular (2/4): selecting text fires click event

Tags: angular

If an element has a `(click)` handler and you select some text within this element, the `(click)` handler gets called. Is there a way to prevent this? [Here's a Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/DDOyX2xG25TcMzv8lVyn?p=preview) illustrating the problem. Relevant code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2 (click)="handleClick()">Click or select this text</h2>
    </div>
  `
})
export class App {
  public handleClick() {
    alert('you clicked');
  }
}
```

Comment: It's happening to me now. The real question is WHY, though :-(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**use this code**

```
public handleClick() {
  var selection = window.getSelection();
  if(selection.toString().length === 0) {
      alert('you clicked');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 8):

Pass the click event (`$event`) to the `handleClick` method

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2 (click)="handleClick($event)">Click or select this text</h2>
    </div>
  `
})
```

Then use the following code to get the selection type:

```
export class App {
  public handleClick(event) {
    if (event.view.getSelection().type !== 'Range') {
      alert('you clicked');
    }
  }
}
```

or:

```
export class App {
  public handleClick(event) {
    if (event.view.getSelection().toString().length === 0) {
      alert('you clicked');
    }
  }
}
```

Plunker demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/PEPyPzDkFjweyAHK8Tj6?p=preview